# TYPO3 x Pixel Facebook - Pixel Facebook detects a potentially infringing element in the search form

Tags: facebook, typo3, pixel

I'm writing to you because I'm an administrator for a health site that uses TYPO3. On this site, we have installed a Facebook Pixel.

For a few days now, it has been detecting a potentially infringing element (health data) in an event.  This analysis is carried out in the website's search bar. The Facebook tool asks us to check these parameters:

- URL request parameter: q
- URL request parameter: tx_solr[q]

Even if I analyse these parameters and the urls in question, I can't correct this analysis.

Honestly, I don't think any data is being circulated, as it's a classic search bar with the option of entering any word.

Have you ever come across this? Should you ignore it and stay alert? Delete the Pixel?

Thank you.

Quentin

I try to seek informations on another communities and i would like advices from theses experts.

Comment: It looks like it's included in a search option, like a form. Ignoring is certainly not a good idea, as it could damage any SEO reputation.

Comment: Thank you @David for your answer. Do you have any advice for me? Should I change or delete this configuration? Or delete this pixel?

Comment: Until you know exactly how to use the pixel correctly I'd remove it entirely.

Comment: @David Thank you for your help. An another expert from an another community Another person advised me to do the same thing.
If a Pixel is deleted, is it possible to reconfigure a new one at a later date?

Comment: If the FB API allows it in general, certainly yes, but I'm not sure if the problem is the pixel itself or the technical implementation. My perspective is just related to SEO, I don't have knowledge concerning these pixels.

Comment: Another aspect is that you might violate the GDPR (DSGVO in German) by using this pixel without consent. https://gdpr-info.eu/

Comment: Hi @David thank your for your answer and your help. I'll try to delete this Pixel... 

Thank you.